# Change a column in a dataframe list and keep the changde dataframe instead of the change output with apply functions

Tags: r

I am trying to alter the contense of a specific coulmn in a list of dataframes in R that has been constructed as such:

```
# Generating a filelist for all summary.txt files that are 3 subdirectories deep from the pwd
filelist = grep(Sys.glob(paste(getwd(), "/*/*/*/*.txt", sep = "")),pattern = "summary.txt", invert = TRUE, value = TRUE )


# Reading in all data files
cazys = lapply(filelist, read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

a typical on of the dataframes will look like this:

```
fam     group     Functions
AA2     3         1.11.1.13:70,
```

I want to split the Functions column by ":" to remove ":70," and similar for every dataframe in the list. I have tried the following:

```
# Correcting the EC number column
fixed_EC = lapply(cazys, function(x){
  x$Functions = strsplit(as.character(x$Functions), ":", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]
} )
```

But this only returns the result of `strplit` and not the alterd dataframe. however when I use this command outside of `apply` it produced the desierd results. How can I get this to work inside an `apply` function?

Comment: Add `return(x)` in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `return(x)` in your current approach should solve it. However, here is a different approach using regex which removes everything after `":"` in `Functions` column.

```
fixed_EC <- lapply(cazys, function(x) 
            transform(x, Functions = sub(':.*', '', Functions)))
```

Comment: Ah thank you,completely forgot about the return fuction :) is there an advantage doing it this way over the way I presented?

Comment: I don't think there is any advantage, it's just a matter of choice. I prefer not to split string if possible.

Comment: What leads you to have this preference?

Comment: Sometimes splitting string can be slow on large dataframes.